# upgrade spark 1.6.1 hadoop ambari

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, bigdata

I have a multi node machine which has Spark 1.6.0 on it but I want to upgrade it to Spark 1.6.1 . Is it possible I can upgrade the Spark version from 1.6.0 to 1.6.1 and if yes then how can I upgrade it?

Can you please provide me in brief.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I don't think v1. 6.1 isn't supported on the latest HDP release, but you are welcome to try.  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_upgrading_hdp_manually/content/upgrade-spark-23.html